# saving email attachments as binary to the database using c#

Tags: email, binary, save, attachment

I can get email attachments from exchange server 2003 (MAPI.Attachment).  How can I save the pdf attachment file as binary into the database?

Here's some code to understand better. For testing purposes I am saving the attachment pdf file into a filesystem. How ca I go about saving that into a database? Or how can I convert that into a byte array? Also, how can I get the size of the file since I need that when I declare the byte array "fileData"...

```
byte[] fileData = new byte[10000];
                string[] fileTokens = new string[2];
                string[] result = new string[3];
                message.Unread = false;
                emailSubject = message.Subject.ToString();
                emailBody = message.Text.ToString();
                MAPI.Attachments test = null;
                test = (MAPI.Attachments)message.Attachments;
                int attachmentCount = (int)test.Count;
                for (int loopCounter = 1; loopCounter <= attachmentCount; loopCounter++)
                {
                    MAPI.Attachment test2 = (MAPI.Attachment)test.get_Item(loopCounter);
                    bool temp = (test2.Name.ToString().Contains(".pdf") && test2.Name.ToString().IndexOf('Q') == 0);
                    if (test2.Name.ToString().Contains(".pdf") && test2.Name.ToString().IndexOf('Q') == 0)
                    {
                        //test2.ReadFromFile(fileData);
                        test2.WriteToFile("d:\\data\\" + test2.Name);
                        PDFParser pdfParser = new PDFParser();
                        pdfParser.ReadPdfFile("d:\\data\\" + test2.Name, result);
                        sentTime = (DateTime)message.TimeSent;
                        string fileName = (string)test2.Name;
                        fileTokens = fileName.Split('.');
                    }
                    RequestHistorySet historySet = new RequestHistorySet(1, sentTime, fileData, fileTokens[1]);
                    bool res = historySet.Update();

                    message.Unread = false;
                    message.Update();
```

And here's the Update function from historySet Class

```
public bool Update()
{
    using (SqlConnection mySqlConnection = ...))
    {
        // Set up the Command object
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("CONNECTION STRING..", mySqlConnection);


        // Set up the OriginalName parameter
        SqlParameter prmId = new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
        prmId.Value = id;
        myCommand.Parameters.Add(prmId);

        SqlParameter prmRequsetDate = new SqlParameter("@requestDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        prmRequsetDate.Value = requestDate;
        myCommand.Parameters.Add(prmRequsetDate);

        // Set up the FileData parameter
        SqlParameter prmFileData = new SqlParameter("@uplodedQuote_File ", SqlDbType.VarBinary);
        prmFileData.Value = fileData;
        prmFileData.Size = fileData.Length;
        myCommand.Parameters.Add(prmFileData);


        SqlParameter prmFileExtension = new SqlParameter("@uplodedQuote_Ext", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        prmFileExtension.Value = fileExtension;
        myCommand.Parameters.Add(prmFileExtension);

        // Execute the command, and clean up.
        mySqlConnection.Open();
        bool result = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0;
        mySqlConnection.Close();

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? Post your code and explain where you are having problems.

Answer (score 0):

As of now this is what I have done. I save it to a filesystem and then read from there.

```
test2.WriteToFile("d:\\data\\" + test2.Name);
fileData = FileToByteArray("d:\\data\\" + test2.Name);
PDFParser pdfParser = new PDFParser();
pdfParser.ReadPdfFile("d:\\data\\" + test2.Name, result);
TryToDelete("d:\\data\\" + test2.Name);
sentTime = (DateTime)message.TimeSent;
string fileName = (string)test2.Name;
fileTokens = fileName.Split('.');
historySet = new RequestHistorySet(1, sentTime, fileData, fileTokens[1]);
```